# CEF can only be initialized once per process. This is a limitation of the underlying CEF/Chromium framework

Tags: c#, cefsharp

I am getting the following error ([shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SKca.png)) on my `Cef.Initialize` call.

> CEF can only be initialized once per process. This is a limitation of the underlying CEF/Chromium framework. You can change many (not all) settings at runtime through RequestContext.SetPreference. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#request-context-browser-isolation Use Cef.IsInitialized to guard against this exception. If you are seeing this unexpectedly then you are likely calling Cef.Initialize after you've created an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, it must be before the first instance is created.

How should I go about troubleshooting this issue?

Answer (score 0):

> If you are seeing this unexpectedly then you are likely calling Cef.Initialize after you've created an instance of ChromiumWebBrowser, it must be before the first instance is created.

You need to check your code to determine where the ChromiumWebBrowser instance is being created or if you are calling Cef.Initialize twice yourself. You've not provided enough code example for someone else to spot the problem.

Did you also add a ChromiumWebBrowser instance via the designer?

A possible resolution and my personal preference is to call Cef.Initialize in Program.Main before the first form is created, this greatly simplifies the logic required.

```cs
namespace CefSharp.MinimalExample.WinForms
{
    public static class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        public static int Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Programmatically enable DPI Aweness
            // Can also be done via app.manifest or app.config
            // https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#high-dpi-displayssupport
            // If set via app.manifest this call will have no effect.
            Cef.EnableHighDPISupport();

            var settings = new CefSettings()
            {
                //By default CefSharp will use an in-memory cache, you need to specify a Cache Folder to persist data
                CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
            };
       
            Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: true, browserProcessHandler: null);

            var browser = new BrowserForm();
            Application.Run(browser);

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (regarding previous deleted comments) In the future, you could also edit the question to fix at least some of the issues and use your knowledge as the maintainer to make the question ask what you're answering (and also help others with the same problem confirm they're looking at the right thing).  I took a crack at it, but I'm not at all familiar with the subject - feel free to double-check my work. (you can also flag this comment as "No longer needed" once you see it)

Answer (score -4):

```
     Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        CefSettings settings = new CefSettings();
        settings.Locale = "tr";
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-path", "pepflashplayer.dll");
        settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("ppapi-flash-version", "99.0.0.999");
        settings.CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "Demon Slayer 3");
        Cef.Initialize(settings);
        Form2 frm = new Form2();
        frm.Tabs.Add(new EasyTabs.TitleBarTab(frm)
        {
            Content = new Form1
            {
                Text = "Yeni Sekme"
            }
        }
        );
        frm.SelectedTabIndex= 0;
        TitleBarTabsApplicationContext applicationContext= new TitleBarTabsApplicationContext();
        applicationContext.Start(frm); 
        Application.Run(applicationContext);
```